# Error "Google.Apis.Auth: Invalid sequence, too long " when trying to use GCP client in C#

Tags: c#, .net, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to use the Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1 Client in C# to publish messages, I have created a service account and downloaded the Json file and also set the path to json file as the environment variable according to [this page](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/libraries), but I keep getting this error `Google.Apis.Auth: Error reading credential file from location /Users/myuser/repositories/auth.json: Invalid sequence, too long.`

Comment: You're taking the correct approach. Please include the relevant subset of your code and the steps that you took in your question. Did you `$env:GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="C:\Users\mysuer\repositories\auth.json"`? Is that the only reference to the key file? There are often issues between Linux and Windows with line-endings in files. The error isn't very helpful but I'd start by checking that key file to ensure it's valid and, if it contains `\r\n`, try replacing with `\n`.

Comment: The error was really confusing , but then I have created a new service account key in GCP and it started working , Thanks @DazWilkin